# Should my .h file and multiple .c files be in the same folder?

Tags: c, directory, header-files

I have one .h file for three .c files. One c file is my program running with a combined student/teacher system (It is a grading system), and then i have a .c file for just the student application and one for just the teacher. They are all in one folder called assignmentgrading3. I am getting an error right now stating:

```
/Users/alessafaria/Documents/assignmentgrading3/assignmentgrading3/Debug && ./assignmentgrading3 
-bash: ./assignmentgrading3: No such file or directory
alessas-MacBook-Air:Debug alessafaria$
```

Should I be separating the files into different folders? (I already tried searching up this answer and do not understand how to use multiple .c files like this as it is my first time)

I have all four files open in tabs on CodeLite, so I don't know if it can't find any of the files or if I am not supposed to be trying to run multiple .c files at the same time?

When I click the assignmentgrading3 folder, there is another one that is named the same thing in it (which contains the .h and .c files) so is it getting confused between the two? (I am providing pictures just in case)

[first assignmentgrading3 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afj6U.png)

[second assignmentgrading3 folder(thats in the first one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGZfH.png)

Comment: Actually one should keep all `.h` file in `inc` and  and all `.c` in `src` directory. Learn `make` concept.  Meanwhile don't keep the links in your question.

Comment: Yes and no, it depends on how you organize the project (e.g. for `gcc` you have the `-I` option to tell the compiler where the .h files are, and similarly for `cl.exe` you have `/I`). But your problem seems irrelevant to this -- it seems you've already successfully compiled and linked the program but have problem to run it.

Comment: @achal so if i make inc and src folders in my assignmentgrading3 folder, the program should be able to find the files?

Comment: For that write `Makefile` and specify the path in that like `VPATH = ./src:./src`

Comment: @Stan my first .c file that has both student/teacher applications together was running perfect. When i made the student .c file and the teacher .c file, thats when it started giving me that error in the terminal, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or how to fix it

Comment: Please show us **the error(s) of compilation given by the compiler** by editing the post. What I could see was only that you got into the directory `/Users/alessafaria/Documents/assignmentgrading3/assignmentgrading3/Debug` and tried to run `./assignmentgrading3` but there's no such an executable file.

Comment: @Stan I didn't show any errors from the compiler because there wasn't any.

Comment: OK, then `cd /Users/alessafaria/Documents/assignmentgrading3/assignmentgrading3/Debug` and then `ls -l`, can you find the executable file `assignmentgrading3`?